# how to use condition on Camel apache

Tags: apache, jboss, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I'm using Camel Apache & fuse on jBoss developement studio  for integration project

i have two endpoints File between them i used as a routing "Choice" to separate files according to theirs extension (xlsx/other) and filename
[image]
on the "When" route i put this expression

```
${file:ext} == 'xlsx' and ${file:onlyname.noext} contains 'FB'
```

and it worked very well now i want to add another condition with OR 
i mean i want both of files whose contains BF or bf 
i used this

```
${file:ext} == 'xlsx' and ${file:onlyname.noext} contains 'FB' or 'fb'
```

and

```
${file:ext} == 'xlsx' and (${file:onlyname.noext} contains 'FB' OR ${file:onlyname.noext} contains 'fb')
```

but it doesn't work

what expression should i write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

Actually the second Code works very Well

```
${file:ext} == 'xlsx' and (${file:onlyname.noext} contains 'FB' OR ${file:onlyname.noext} contains 'fb')
```